# SAPUI5: Can a Smartfield be used in place of an Input?

Tags: sapui5

Using a standard oData service provided by SAP Gateway (no annotations).

SAPUI5 v1.77.2 (not Fiori Elements)

Can a Smartfield be used in place of an input SAPUI5 component?

For example..

Can this:

```
 <Input value="{parts: ['pendingData>/data/netPrice', 'pendingData>/data/currency'], type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency', formatOptions: {showMeasure: false} }" id="pendingNetPriceInput" change="onInputChange"/>
```

Be replaced with this (I've included the smartField xmlns):

```
 <smartField:SmartField value="{pendingData>/data/netPrice}" id="pendingNetPriceInput" change="onInputChange"/>
```

The reason for doing this is to get currency input validation functioning correctly.

On the input component, frontend currency validation does not appear to work for currencies that don't allow a decimal point (E.g. JPY).

https://answers.sap.com/questions/13871488/sapui5-input-currency-not-validating-decimal-poiin.html

However, JPY currency validation looks to be functioning fine using a smartField given in this example:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smartfield.SmartField/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfield.CurrencyValidation

When I try to implement the SmartField, nothing is shown, although I can see the smartField class has been generated when I inspect the HTML

```
<div id="__xmlview2--pendingPricePerInput" data-sap-ui="__xmlview2--pendingPricePerInput" class="sap
```

Comment: Basically you can use smartfield controlls without annotation, but they behave the same as you would use a normal input field for e.g. (this was my experience). Did you consider to use a formatter? you can implement by yourself the logic for the different currencys on base of your selection